# How can I integrate my environment variables in my file?

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, next.js, stripe-payments

I have implemented a Stripe Checkout session, and now I want to use environment variables to hide my API keys. However, whenever I run my folder after interpolating my env keys, I would get an Authentication error saying my API key returned undefined.
Error:

```js
type: 'StripeAuthenticationError',
  raw: {
    message: 'Invalid API Key provided: undefined',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
```

env.local

```js
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = Made up numbers, i.e. 1234
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = 1234
PRICE_ID = 1234
```

checkout.tsx

```js
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"

const stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}`);

...
```

Comment: Does `process.env` actually contain your variables?  Also does it help if you remove the spaces on each side of the `=`?

Comment: Yes I am using next.js. It doesn't help to remove the whitespace between the =. Lastly, I assumed that process.env contains my variables, but it's returning undefined. I'm not sure how to interpolate my variables any other way.

Comment: Are you trying to use the environment variables in client-side code? If you need to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. See [Exposing Environment Variables to the Browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) for details.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the server whenever you change or add environment variables! Or refer to @juliomalves response above.